# Mathematica gives an unexpected answer for Integrate

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, functions, trigonometry, integral-equations

I need to integrate the following:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\frac{\sqrt{C + (1 - C) x^3}}{x},
\end{equation}
where $0 < C < 1$ and $x$ is a *positive variable* (then $x^3 \ge 0$).  When I integrate:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/x, x, Assumptions -> 0 < C < 1]
```

I get this answer:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{C + (1 - C)\, x^3} - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{C} \, \mathrm{argtanh} \Big( \frac{\sqrt{C + (1 - C) \, x^3}}{\sqrt{C}} \Big).
\end{equation}
This answer is wrong because the term inside parenthesis (inside the argtanh) is larger than 1, which invalidates the answer.

So how can I get the proper integration of (1), using Mathematica?

---

**EDIT:**  Actually, what I need is to find the general solution of the following differential equation ($\lambda$ is a positive constant):
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\frac{d a}{d t} = \pm \, \frac{\lambda \, a}{\sqrt{C + (1 - C) \, a^3}},
\end{equation}
i.e. the function $a(t)$ or the time $t(a)$.

Comment: When evaluating a definite integral don't the imaginary parts cancel out?

Comment: @JimB, I need the general solution on the indefinite integration, since I don't know the limits of the variable $x$ (except that $x > 0$).  It's the solution of some differential equation.

Comment: You should change the subject line of the question from "wrong" to perhaps "unexpected" since `Assuming[{0<C<1, x>=0}, Sqrt[C+(1-C) x^3]/x == D[Integrate[Sqrt[C+(1-C) x^3]/x, x], x] // Simplify]` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Tha antiderivative shown is fine. Can check by differentiation: `In[646]:= i0 = Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/x;
i1 = Integrate[i0, x];
Simplify[D[i1, x] - i0]

Out[648]= 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\int\frac{\sqrt{C + (1 - C) x^3}}{x}dx=\int\frac{\left(\sqrt{C + (1 - C) x^3}\right)x^2}{x^3}dx$

Let    $C + (1 - C) x^3=u^2$

$3(1 - C) x^2dx=2udu$

$\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{u^2du}{u^2-C}du$

$\frac{2}{3}\int\left(1+\frac{c}{u^2-C}\right)du$

$\frac{2}{3}\left(u+C\int\frac{du}{u^2-\sqrt{C}^2}\right)$

$\frac{2}{3}\left(u-C\frac{Arctanh(\frac{u}{\sqrt{C}})}{\sqrt{C}}\right)$

Substituting back gives

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{C + (1 - C)\, x^3} - \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{C} \, \mathrm{argtanh} \Big( \frac{\sqrt{C + (1 - C) \, x^3}}{\sqrt{C}} \Big).
\end{equation}

```
FunctionDomain[ArcTanh[Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/Sqrt[C]], x]
```

> -1 < Sqrt[C + x^3 - C x^3]/Sqrt[C] < 1 && -C - x^3 + C x^3 <= 0

Or

```
 ArcTanh[Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/Sqrt[C]] // TrigToExp
```

> -(1/2) Log[1 - Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/Sqrt[C]] +   1/2 Log[1 + Sqrt[C + (1 - C) x^3]/Sqrt[C]]

Comment: There's still a problem with the argument of arctanh.

Comment: I think it's better to split the integral of $\frac{1}{u^2 - C}$ in two parts : $\frac{1}{u - \sqrt{C}} - \frac{1}{u + \sqrt{C}}$, then integration gives a $\ln{\dots}$.

Comment: They are equivalent..

Comment: My solution appears to be this: \begin{equation} \frac{2 u}{3 \sqrt{C}} + \frac{1}{3} \, \ln{\Big(\frac{u - \sqrt{C}}{u + \sqrt{C}}\Big)},\end{equation} which is good since $u \ge \sqrt{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

Here are <s>four</s> <s>five</s> six forms for an antiderivative, the first `ad1` being the same as the OP's and complex-valued over the intended domain.  The other <s>three</s> <s>four</s> five are real-valued.

```
ad1 = Integrate[Sqrt[c + (1 - c) x^3]/x, x, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1]
(*  2/3 Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] - 2/3 Sqrt[c] ArcTanh[Sqrt[c + (1 - c) x^3]/Sqrt[c]]  *)
```

The imaginary part of `ad` is constant so we can subtract it off (which is the point of @JimB's comment under the OP):

```
ad2 = ad1 /. {{x -> 1}, {x -> x}} // Differences // First;

Assuming[0 < c < 1 && x > 0,
 TrigToExp@ad2 /. {Log[z_] /; Simplify[z < 0] :> Log[-1] + Log[-z]} // 
   Expand // FullSimplify
 ]
(*
2/3 (-1 + Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] + 
   Sqrt[c] ArcTanh[(Sqrt[c] (x^3 - Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]))/(c + x^3)])
*)
```

Applying the identity,
$$\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) - \tanh ^{-1}(z)=\frac{i \pi}{2} \,,$$
changes `ad1` by a constant, which results in another antiderivative:

```
ad3 = ad1 /. ArcTanh[z_] :> ArcTanh[1/z]
(*  2/3 Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] - 2/3 Sqrt[c] ArcTanh[Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[c + (1 - c) x^3]] *)
```

Rewrite `ad3` in terms of logarithms:

```
ad4 = TrigToExp@ad3 /. 
  a__ Log[u_] + b__ Log[v_] + w__ /; Times@a == -Times@b :> a Log@Simplify[u/v] + w
(*
  2/3 Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] + 
   1/3 Sqrt[c] Log[(-Sqrt[c] + Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]) /
     (Sqrt[c] + Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3])]
*)
```

Check:

```
D[{ad1, ad2, ad3, ad4}, x] // Simplify
(*
  {Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]/x, Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]/x,
   Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]/x, Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]/x}
*)
```

*Addendum:*
Here is a fifth, the real part of `ad1`:

```
ad5 = ComplexExpand[Re[ad1], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
 Simplify[#, 0 < c < 1 && x > (c/(1 - c))^(1/3)] &
(*
  1/6 (4 Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] + 
     Sqrt[c] Log[(x^3 - c (-2 + x^3) - 2 Sqrt[c (c + x^3 - c x^3)])/c] -
     Sqrt[c] Log[(x^3 - c (-2 + x^3) + 2 Sqrt[c (c + x^3 - c x^3)])/c])
*)
```

*Addendum 2:*
Doing a line integral within the domain of interest will often give the desired result; however, this time it ran forever, until I turned off `GenerateConditions`.  The antiderivative comes back in terms of `HypergeometricPFQ` which can be simplified with the aid of `FunctionExpand`.

```
Assuming[0 < c < 1 && x > 0 && t > 0, 
 ad6 = Simplify@ FunctionExpand@
    Integrate[Sqrt[c + (1 - c) t^3]/t, {t, 1, x}, 
     Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1 && x > 0, GenerateConditions -> False]
 ]
(*
  1/3 (-2 + 2 Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3] + 2 Sqrt[c] Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[c]] + 
     3 Sqrt[c] Log[x] - 2 Sqrt[c] Log[1 + Sqrt[1 + (-1 + 1/c) x^3]])
*)

(* Check *)
Simplify[D[ad6, x] - Sqrt[c + x^3 - c x^3]/x, 0 < c < 1 && x > 0]
```